# How to pass an object from pug to front end javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pugjs

I´m using pug and I want to pass a variable to the front end for information, but when I´m trying to do that it pass like a text.

This is how I do that.

Controller code:

```
res.render('view/edit', {
     title: 'Title',
     sub:true,
     data: variableObject
 });
```

This is the code in the rendered view:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    var x = "#{data}"
    console.log(x);
```

And this is the result of the log

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

I can´t access to the object because is text, is there a way to pass the object like an object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I used this:

```
var x = "#{ JSON.stringify(y) }"
   console.log( JSON.parse(x.replace(/&quot;/g,'"')) );
```

I´m not sure if this is the best practice.

Comment: as in dNitro's answer, Using `!{JSON.stringify(y)}` removes the escaping issue.

Answer (score 24):

First stringify your object using `JSON.stringify`:

```
res.render('view/edit', {
     title: 'Title',
     sub: true,
     data: JSON.stringify(variableObject)
 });
```

Then use [String Interpolation, Unescaped](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped) `!{data}`

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    var x = !{data}
    console.log(x);
```

---

Or just do it all once, in your template:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    var x = !{JSON.stringify(data)}
    console.log(x);
```

(kudos to @Matt, Thanks)

Comment: If the string contains `</script>` this will create problems because the browser will think it's the closing tab of the opening `<script>`. Is there any simple solution for that?

Comment: is there a way to do this the opposite way? pug allows say with an dynamic array that is created after the page renders?